# ¿Como puedo agregar números a una impresión en la pantalla de una lista de paths?

Tags: python

Hola soy novato en el python y este es código:

```
import os, sys

path = 'PLO-2010'
total = 0

files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files

for r, d, f in os.walk(path):

    for file in f:

        if ".fits" in file:
            f.sort()
            files.append(os.path.join(r, file))

            total +=1

for f in files:

    print(f)

print(total)
```

Con este programa logro visualizar en el terminal una lista de archivos guardados en una carpeta y su path, lo que necesito es agregarle un número a cada archivo y que esto me figure en la pantalla.
Alguna ayuda por favor

Comment: Te refieres que salgan por la terminal enumerados?

Comment: Siii, eso necesito

Answer (score 3):

Puedes utilizar la función [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) que devuelve una tupla que contiene un recuento y el/los valor/es del iterable.

```
files = ["/home/asd/aa", "/home/bb/bb"]

for i,f in enumerate(files):
    print("{}# {}".format(i,f))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la idea